# Newbie C# -- object casting at runtime

Tags: c#

Much appreciate any help....

Problem:
Choice of three different types to be applied at runtime, want to have local variable converted to type depending on result.

Example:

```
Object test; 

if (something == somethingElse)
{
   test = VendorClass<VendorType>
}
else
{
   test = OtherVendorClass<OtherVendorType>
}
```

I've looked around StackOverflow and found some good examples, such as

```
var newVar = (OtherVendorClass<OtherVendorType>)test;
```

and

```
var newVar = test as OtherVendorClass<OtherVendorType>;
```

However, all I've seen so far don't the test variable scope, just create new ones locally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really very clear what you're asking here; can you add some more detail?

Comment: How you are going to use your `test` object after casting?

Comment: Wow....looks like I did something very wrong looking at the negative votes. Can someone advise where I'm going wrong and let me know? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to change the type of the variable `test`, the answer is:

You can't. You also can't define the variable with different types, dependent on some condition.

You CAN however pick a type for `test` that is so general, that it fits all objects you want to put in. `object` for instance.

```
object test;
if (condition)
    test = new VendorClass<VendorType>()
else
    test = new OtherVendorClass<OtherVendorType>()
```

This code is valid, the only problem being, that every time you want to access the object you saved in `test`, you have to cast it back to the correct type.

```
if(condition)
    ((VendorClass<VendorType>)test).vendorMethod();
else
    ((OtherVendorClass<OtherVendorType>)test).vendorMethod();
```

A more elegant solution would be, to find or define another type than `object`, that is general enough to hold all these types, but precise enough to have all the properties that you need to access.

Being "general enough" meaning that `VendorClass<T>` and `OtherVendorClass<T>` both inherit from it, but at this point i would refer you to the C# manual for Inheritance.
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)

EDIT: Such a type could also be an Interface, that both types are implementing. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

Also feel free to post better resources than the c# manual, there are without a doubt better explanations of inheritance and interfaces in C# out there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you declare a variable - `test` - and then that variable might contain an object of one type, another type, or some other type, then what are you going to do with that object next? The whole point of a strongly-typed language is that we know the type of each object we're working with, or at least know something about its type.

If those various types all implement some common interface then you can do this:

```
ISomeCommonInterface myObject = null;

if(something == true)
    myObject = new SomethingThatImplementsThatCommonInterface();
else
    myObject = new SomethingElseThatImplementsThatCommonInterface();
```

I'm not saying that's good practice, but it works. Going forward, you know that `myObject` is an instance of `ISomeCommonInterface`. So you deal with that interface and don't care anymore what the actual implementation is.

(That also works if the types inherit from the declared type, or one is the declared type and the others inherit.)

Otherwise all you could do is declare your variable as type `object`. Now you can assign any type you want to it, but again that defeats the purpose of strong typing. We always want to have an object cast as some known, predetermined type so that we know how to use it or interact with it. We never want to have an `object` and then implement "if it's this type, call this method, but if it's that type, call that method."

Comment: You're welcome! As a general rule of thumb, something is wrong if we're declaring variables as `object` or if we have an object and we're writing any code to try to figure out what its type is. (Neither of those are absolutes, but they will get you far.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a type check on your object using the `is` keyword.

```
if (myObject is MyFirstType)
{
     MyFirstType obj = (MyFirstType)myObject;
     obj.MyFirstTypeMethod();
}
else if (myObject is MySecondType)
{
     MySecondTypeobj = (MySecondType)myObject;
     obj.MySecondTypeMethod();
}
```

Comment: It's not recommended to do this; in effect you're casting the object twice.  Much better to try `var foo = myObject as Foo;` then test `foo` isn't null.

Comment: Whether you do `obj = (MyFirstType)myObject` or `myObject as MyFirstType`, it's a situation you don't want to be in. It's not a 100% all-the-time rule, but strongly-typed code should be written so that we already know what type we're dealing with and don't have to inspect the object to find out what its type is. We don't have to know the *actual* type - just an interface it implements or a base class it inherits from. Then the benefit is that we can work with the *known* type without even knowing the *actual* type.